# Subselect query with count combining three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three mysql tables. `notification_tbl`, `section_tbl`  and `user_plant_tbl`.

`user_plant_tbl` has **plants** and one **plant** may have multiple **sections** in `section_tbl` table. `notification_tbl` has all closed and open notification with **sections**. What I want is to get all **sections(ex: section name)** and **counts** of all **closed notifications** from `notification_tbl` table for that particular **section**.

section_tbl

```
section_id      plant
sectionX        2400
sectionY        2400
```

user_plant_tbl

```
user_id  plant
3001     2400
3003     2200
```

notification_tbl

```
notification_id    plant   section_id      open_flag
60000062           2400    sectionX        x
60000063           2400    sectionX        x
60000064           2400    sectionX        x
60000063           2400    sectionY        x
60000064           2400    sectionY        x
```

For example lets see **sectionX** has **3** closed notification rows in `notification_tbl` table and **2** for **sectionY**. Then i want to get a output,

```
sectionX 3
sectionY 2
```

This is the query I used and it doesn't give me the desired output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.section_id,
    (SELECT count(section_id) FROM notification_tbl WHERE open_flag = 'x') AS countx
FROM
    section_tbl AS a
INNER JOIN user_plant_tbl AS b ON a.plant = b.plant
WHERE
    b.user_id = 3001
    AND b.plant = 2400
    AND a.division = 7
GROUP BY
    a.section_id
ORDER BY
    countx DESC;
```

Comment: try to relate your tables also in the subquery like: `(SELECT count(section_id) FROM notification_tbl as ntbl JOIN section_tbl as stbl on stbl.column_that_relates_with_ntbl = ntbl.column_that_relates_with_stbl and stbl.section_id = a.section_id WHERE open_flag = 'x' )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your example there is a `section_id` column in the `notification_tbl` too, thus you can relate the `section_tbl` and the `notification_tbl` joining them on that column. The following query gives an answer:

```
SELECT
    s.section_id,
    COUNT(n.section_id) AS count_closed
FROM section_tbl AS s
INNER JOIN notification_tbl AS n ON n.section_id = s.section_id
INNER JOIN user_plant_tbl AS u ON s.plant = u.plant
WHERE
    u.user_id = 3001
    AND u.plant = 2400
    AND s.division = 7
    AND n.open_flag = 'X'
GROUP BY
    s.section_id
ORDER BY
    count_closed DESC;
```

***Update:***

Based on your comments I modified the query in order to get those results too.

```
SELECT
    s.section_id,
    SUM(case when n.open_flag = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) AS count_closed,
    SUM(case when n.open_flag <> 'X' then 1 else 0 end) AS count_opened 
FROM section_tbl AS s
INNER JOIN notification_tbl AS n ON n.section_id = s.section_id
INNER JOIN user_plant_tbl AS u ON s.plant = u.plant
WHERE
    u.user_id = 3001
    AND u.plant = 2400
GROUP BY
    s.section_id
ORDER BY
    count_closed DESC;
```

See **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ce3b/4)**.

Then take into account the newly inserted sections that have neither opened or closed status flag yet.

```
SELECT
    s.section_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN n.open_flag = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_closed
FROM section_tbl AS s
LEFT JOIN notification_tbl AS n ON s.section_id = n.section_id
INNER JOIN user_plant_tbl AS u ON s.plant = u.plant
WHERE
    u.user_id = 3001
    AND u.plant = 2400
GROUP BY
    s.section_id
ORDER BY
    count_closed DESC;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6abfb/5)**

Comment: I also wanted to get other sections that exist in **section_tbl** that open_flag <>  'X' count as 0

Comment: @D.Madu i updated the answer to count opened sections too.

Comment: hey thank for your time, but it not really what i looking for. i think because of my bad English you misunderstood it.  i modify your demo, if you can please look. there I have done some modification to section_tbl. your count working nicely. what i asked to come as 0 , i meant that for ex: newly added sectionZ is not in the notification_tbl even closed or open. That should also need to come to the final output as 0. All sections exist in section_table need to come, if closed record exist in notification_table  that should come as count.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6abfb/1

Comment: @D.Madu I got your point ;). Then this **[query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6abfb/5)** should solve your problem. Then where is no open or closed notification for a new section we should remove the filter `n.open_flag = 'x'`